# Match sequence at the very beginning of a string along with other sequences in the middle

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a way to match 2 patterns in the same regular expression, but I can't seem to be able to combine both. These are a few strings I'm trying to match against:

```
0 800-204-4000
0800-204 4000
0 800 -204 - 4000
800 204 4000
```

What I'm trying to do is find a regular expression that matches a zero at the beginning of a string if it exists and all subsequent white spaces and dashes. So I was able to match the first zero if it exists using `/^0?/` and match all empty spaces and dashes using `/[\s-]*/g` but how exactly can I combine both into the same expression?

Edit:

So I want to match the first 0 IF it exists and all following spaces and dashes. So in the examples above, what should be matched is in brackets:

```
[0 ]800[-]204[-]4000
[0]800[-]204[ ]4000
[0 ]800[ -]204[ - ]4000
800[ ]204[ ]4000
```

The regex provided in the answers do not work. Check it out: https://regex101.com/r/dMN6xR/1

Comment: What is so unique here? Only whitespace, digits and hyphens? Try just [`/^[\s\d-]+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/IoFQXw/1).

Comment: It is unclear which spaces and dashes you want to match.

Comment: throw some more examples in here.  these should match, these should not match.  The 4 listed above, the first 3 should match, and the last shouldn't because it doesn't start with a zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(^0|[\s-])[\s-]*`

To avoid empty matches, set up a match group `()` that matches starting zero `^0` or `|` whitespace/- `[\s-]`, and then match rest of whitespace/- `[\s-]*`

To allow whitespace before the zero, just add that right after the start anchor like this

`(^[\s-]*0|[\s-])[\s-]*`.

Comment: All the other answers here got really close to what I wanted and I acknowledge that I did not specify that it should match the first zero, regardless of whether there were spaces at the beginnig or not but your answer was the closest. Thank you. If you edit your regex to match also the first zero like this: (^0|[\s-]+0?)[\s-]* ill choose yours as the right answer

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães is there a case my regex doesn't cover? I left out flags like "g - global/ m- multi-line" since you didn't specify what regex flavor you are using. But if there are any cases you need this to cover/not cover, just let me know and I'll update the answer. (Also, does the explanation make sense enough that you understand what it is doing enough to modify it to your needs?)

Comment: the only thing your regex does not cover is " 0888" when the string starts with an empty space. I wanted the regex to match the first character being a zero even if the first character is a space. This is how i changed it. Not sure it is the best expression for what I need. What do you think? (^0|[\s-]+0?)[\s-]*

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães ah, I thought that was an invalid case because you said `/^0?/` worked. Your adjustment allows 0 to get matched anywhere, so you need to adjust the part with the start anchor like this `(^[\s-]*0|[\s-])[\s-]*`. That way, it says "Match any whitespace/- and 0 at the start of the string, or whitespace/- anywhere in the string".

Answer (score 2):

You combine the regex by using the or operator:

```
/(^0?)|[\s-]*/g
```

When simplified, it would be

```
/(^0)?[\s-]+/g
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't clearly understand your first question. Changing answer.

Comment: Why make 0 optional and an OR? You should probably also filter out the empty strings from the results.

Comment: Good comments. Changed but left first as better showing combination of original RE from question.

Comment: `/(^0?)|[\s-]*/g` and `/(^0)?[\s-]+/g` are not equivalent. The first one can match the empty string, and the second one requires at least 1 whitespace or - (won't match only a leading zero)

Comment: The point is the original question asked how to combine the two Regex, not how to create a new regex to accomplish something possibly similar. The or is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing on the others' answers, you can [use `/^0[-\s]*|[-\s]+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/ewkSLe/3).  I've used `[- ]` in the demo because I don't like how difficult it is to read when newlines are removed.

Comment: That will match "starting zero" or "1+ space/-", so that will match "0 1" as two matches instead of one. (and ' ' is more restrictive than \s, so they aren't equivalent. \s also matches new lines/tabs)

Comment: @Tezra I see. I was interpreting OP as saying "one expression" only, but looking back, I think you're correct.  OP wants the matches to be combined too.